# Spiky COMMIT results in performance slowdowns with Postgres 8.4

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-performance

We just installed performance monitoring on our web application, and we're seeing a spiky pattern in response times from our Postgres 8.4 server. The spikes correspond with significant slowdown in our web app. The time seems to taken up largely in "Postgres commit":

[image: Top database operations by time consumed]

We're self-hosting Postgres 8.4.3 on Ubuntu 10.04, with essentially stock settings, on an Amazon EC2 c1.xlarge instance w/ EBS. Yes, I know that Postgres on EBS probably isn't the best setup. We plan to move to a newer Postgres DB on RDS later this year.

In the meantime, is there anything obvious that I should look at that might tame this spiky pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly your graphs say.  But `commit` is designed to be slow.  By default, Postgres [waits for changes to be written to disk](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-wal.html) before it lets `commit` return.

You can let `commit` complete before changes are written to disk with this option:

```
synchronous_commit = off
```

That should certainly help to spread the disk I/O required for `commit` over more time.  The downside is that a server outage can cause completed transactions to be lost.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I think that helps me connect the dots. We have a large indexing job that runs every 15 minutes. It doesn't write, but it does entire-table queries on two tables that *are* occasionally written to. All that I/O contention would probably delay the WAL, right?

Comment: That is quite possible, but there are a lot of variables in play